# php multiple sites to one site with relative sub domains

Tags: php, redirect, alias, subdomain

I'm looking a bit of advise on an issue i've not dealt with before and appears to be very vague regarding advise, most info i could find was tied to Wordpress unfortunately

My problem is related to consolidating multiple sites into one with relative sub domains.
I have a site that for anonymitys sake i'll call www.abc.com
I also have www.abc.co.uk and www.abc.ie

What i want to do is have the three sites all point to www.abc.com with a url stucture like

www.abc.com/region1
www.abc.com/region2
www.abc.com/region3

The problem is i've no experience regarding where to start into doing something like this. I know I could create 3 sub directories under the httpdocs pointing to the regions but what I would like to do is point at the one set of files and store variables in the $_SESSION to determine which region the user wants. What I would like to do then is redirect the .ie and .co.uk to the .com with the relevant region info after the .com/

From what i gather reading around the sub directories would create a host of seperate content on google and my main reason for wanting to consolidate the sites into one is to promote my google rank

If anyone could offer me any advise or point me to an article explaining how this may be possible I would be very greatful

Many thanks

Barry

Comment: What webserver are yoiu using, or are you planning to use ?

Comment: I'm using a VPS running Ubunto 10.04 with Parallels Plesk 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds more like a server installation question, than PHP question. What web server are you using for your server ?

**Long, boring, descriptive answer**

You must understand that:

**(1) subfolders**

```
www.abc.com/uk [/index.html]
www.abc.com/ireland [/index.html]
www.abc.com/australia [/index.html]
```

**(2) conceptually related websites**

```
www.abc.co.uk [/index.html]
www.abc.co.ie [/index.html]
www.abc.co.au [/index.html]
```

**(3) subwebsites**

```
uk.abc.co [/index.html]
ireland.abc.co [/index.html]
australia.abc.co [/index.html]
```

**(4) And, redirection**

(4.1) Redirection to subfolder

```
www.abc.co.uk [/index.html] => www.abc.com/uk [/index.html]
www.abc.co.ie [/index.html] => www.abc.com/ireland [/index.html]
www.abc.co.au [/index.html] => www.abc.com/australia [/index.html]
```

(4.2) Redirection to subwebsite

```
www.abc.co.uk [/index.html] => england.www.abc.com [/index.html]
www.abc.co.ie [/index.html] => ireland.www.abc.com [/index.html]
www.abc.co.au [/index.html] => australia.www.abc.com [/index.html]
```

All of them look similar, but, in reality, they are different things, differents solutions, that may solve the same problem ?

Redirection (4.1) & (4.2) can be used as a trick for (2) & (3).

**Quick answer**

There is a learning process here. I strongly suggest, do this, step by step, if you can. Specially, because you are also in charge of the programming:

(1) I suggest to start with a single domain, using subfolders, have a single start page for each subfolder, as separate stuff.

(2) Later, You may want to buy the separate, additional domains.

If you have your own web server, you must configure it to redirect the domains to each folder. So when a user writes to a localized domain in his browser, the server redirects him to a subfolder.

If you are using or plan to use a web hosting provider, some of the allow you to sell only the domain, and redirect the domain to other domain, or domain with subfolder, in their configuration page.

(3) Avoid subwebsites. Requires more configuration, both in your web server, or your PHP website. And, for your case, subfolders, seems a better choice.

**Extra**

Your question may be best answered in the web apps forum:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

or the server forum:

https://serverfault.com/

Cheers.

Comment: That's a great response umlcat, and looking at the methods 4.1 would be the one I would be aiming to use. I've already got all the domains purchased and pointing to IP addresses tied to my VPS.Do you think the sub folders approach would be my best option? Using one set of resource files from say an includes directory?

Comment: @BarryH1987: The info you provide, subfolders better, and redirection later. Have own web-server, may have shared resources folder for global or all images & files, and optional another separate folder for very specific resources ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The start point for this is in your DNS settings. All domains must be routed towards the same server.

After that you use either

- httpd.conf: /etc/apache2/
- vhosts: /etc/apache2/sites-available/yoursite-name
- .htaccess

Httpd.conf or vhosts have the following format:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName x.com
    ServerAlias www.x.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/region1
</VirtualHost>
```

And they are not dynamically configurable. Meaning that you have to write/change the vhosts files then restart apache2 to reload these configuration directives.

If you're in a shared hosting, there are a few options such as **addon domains** and **parked domains**.

Addons let you specify a directory (within your public_html) where you want the code for that domain to be.

Parked domains overlap with your default domain and you need the .htaccess to redirect all traffic for domain x.com to domain y.com.

Comment: Hi Mihai
I know how to configure the DNS, so thats step 1 ok, but step 2 is throwing me. I've only used .htaccess files before. Under my var/www/ directory i've got my namespaces for the domains i have on my VPS so where would i need to go from there? does each region need a namespace?